# Оптимизация решения на C++

Tags: c++, массивы, оптимизация, матрицы

Всем доброго времени суток, задача такая:
Найти элемент произведения (с заданными i и j) какого-то количества матриц. При вычислении произведения применяется следующее правило - если результат операции выходит большим либо равным некоторого простого числа P (часть входных данных), то результат этой операции заменяется на остаток от деления на число P.
Задача [отсюда](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/school/io/archive/20051112/problems-advanced.pdf), под буквой C.

Проблема во времени выполнения - я написал некоторый код, выполняющийся верно, однако вычисление всего произведения занимает слишком много времени. Кажется, нужно считать только необходимую часть матричного произведения, но я не могу понять, какую именно. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

**Входные данные:**

```
3 2

1 2

239

1 2
3 4

4 2
1 3

1 2
2 1
```

**Выходные данные:**

```
20
```

**Написанная мной программа:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
 
void Nullify(int matrix[][201], int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
 
void Multiple(int mat1[][201], int mat2[][201], int mat3[][201], int n, int p)
{
    Nullify(mat3, n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
            {
                mat3[i][j] += ((mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]) % p);
                mat3[i][j] %= p;
            }
        }
    }
}
 
void InputMatrix(int matrix[][201], int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    int currentMatrix[201][201] = { 0 };
    int result[201][201] = { 0 };
    int temp[201][201] = { 0 };
     
    int quanity;
    int n;
 
    int x, y;
 
    int p;
 
    cin >> quanity >> n;
    cin >> x >> y;
    cin >> p;
 
    bool flag = true;
 
    InputMatrix(temp, n);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < quanity - 1; i++)
    {
        InputMatrix(currentMatrix, n);
        if (flag)
        {
            Multiple(temp, currentMatrix, result, n, p);
            flag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Multiple(result, currentMatrix, temp, n, p);
            flag = true;
        }
    }
     
    if (flag)
    {
        cout << temp[x][y];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << result[x][y];
    }
 
     
}
```

Comment: Как обычно - дайте-ка URL задания, чтобы посмотреть в оригинале...

Comment: @Harry, В вопросе оставил ссылку (в виде гиперссылки) на задачу, но дублирую: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/school/io/archive/20051112/problems-advanced.pdf (задача C)

Comment: А проверяющей системы нет?..

Comment: @Harry, да, конечно, вот задача на ACMP, стоило сразу прикрепить эту ссылку: https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, в общем, идея в том, что не надо `m*n*n*n` операций - всю матрицу считать. Достаточно взять только a-ю строку, и работать с ней (ну сами смотрите формулу умножения... если нас интересует только элемент в a-й строке...)

Но все это так и не хотело работать, пока не вспомнил, что GNU-сные компиляторы страшно ускоряют чтение с помощью двух строк отвязки от синхронизации с вводом-выводом C. И тут оно таки заработало...

Вобщем, вот...

```
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    int m, n, a, b, p;
    cin >> m >> n >> a >> b >> p;
    --a; --b;
    vector<int> A(n), C(n);

    cin.ignore(100000,'\n');
    cin.ignore(100000,'\n');

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (i == a)
            for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) cin >> A[j];
        cin.ignore(100000,'\n');
    }

    for(int k = 1; k < m; ++k)
    {
        C = vector<int>(n);
        for(int l = 0; l < n; ++l)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                int x;
                cin >> x;
                C[j] += A[l]*x;
            }
        }
        for(int l = 0; l < n; ++l)
            A[l] = C[l]%p;
    }
    cout << A[b] << endl;
}
```

Только уж постарайтесь понять сами, как оно работает, ладно? :)

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, обнуление элементов матрицы(функция `Nullify`) совершенно
лишняя операция, так как вы потом все равно их инициализируете.
Соответственно, из функции `Multiple` уберите ее вызов.

Во вторых, Последнюю матрицу не нужно умножать. Если результат умножения всех предыдущих  матриц, это матрица `result`(если матриц всего два, то `result` это первая матрица), то нужно просто вывести сумму умножения строки `result[x]` на столбец `y` последней матрицы. Но последняя матрица тоже не нужна в принципе, потому что вы просто можете читать столбец из потока ввода:

```
int answer = 0, t;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= y; ++j) {
        cin >> t;  //читаем пока не дойдем до элемента соответствующего столбца
        cin.ignore(n, '\n'); //пропускаем остальную строку
    }
    answer += result[x][i] * t;
}
cout << answer%p;
```